# Configure SAP .NET Connector for SNC using config file in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, sap-basis, sap-dotnet-connector

We have a number of applications developed in C# that interface with SAP using the SAP .NET Connector 3.0. I'm very familiar with this, and have recently been asked to look at securing this interface by using the SNC (Secure Network Communications) options, which I've also been able to configure and get working.

However, I want to configure my SNC destinations entirely via config file and not programmatically. To specify an *unsecure* connection, I can specify the following destination in the config file:

```
<SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>          
          <add NAME="MySAPName" USER="MyUser" PASSWD="orly" CLIENT="100" LANG="EN" ASHOST="mysapname.mydomain.com" SYSNR="70" MAX_POOL_SIZE="20" IDLE_TIMEOUT="10"/>          
        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
</SAP.Middleware.Connector>
```

But, to create a *secure* SNC connection, so far I've only figured out how to do it by configuring the destination programatically, e.g.:

```
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "mysapname.mydomain.com");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Name, "MySAPName"); 
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "70");                                              
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "100");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User,"MyUser");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "orly");                    

  // Additional Params for SNC, not settable in config?
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncMode, "8");                    
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName, "p:CN=RemovedForConfidentiality, OU=, O=, L=,C=GB");                                                            
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncMyName, "p:CN=MyRemovedPartnerName, C=GB, O=, OU=");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SncQOP, "8");
  Params.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Trace, "2");
```

So, given this context my question is: Can I configure an SNC based SAP Destination using only the config file? If so, how?

I realise I could store SncPartnerName etc. in AppSettings but it would be much nicer if it were specifiable in the DestinationConfiguration section. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, however. I should note I'm aware of the the SAP SCN website and have had an unfruitful look on [there](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm700_ehp02/helpdata/EN/5b/617bcd479b46a1829ac0d7886903fb/content.htm), although I do not have access to the SAP Service Marketplace.

Comment: Have you checked the Appendix A of the programming guide? This fives an overview of the parameters, including the SNC params.

Comment: Do you have the Url? I can only find the "SAP .Net Connector Programmer's Reference", which doesn't seem to have Appendices.

Comment: http://service.sap.com/connectors --> SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET --> Download SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET Version 3.0 --> NCo_30_ProgrammingGuide.pdf

Comment: As I stated in the question, I don't have access to the SAP Service Marketplace

Comment: Then someone in your company has to have access to the SMP, otherwise you're probably using the connector illegally...

Comment: I can assure you we're not using it illegally. Was hoping someone would just know so I can avoid the bureacracy of getting hold of this document!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine has managed to discover the solution. Sample config file with the parameters required for SNC is as follows:

```
<SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>          
          <add NAME="MySAPName" USER="MyUser" PASSWD="orly" CLIENT="100" LANG="EN"
                ASHOST="mysapname.mydomain.com" SYSNR="70" MAX_POOL_SIZE="20" IDLE_TIMEOUT="10"
                SNC_PARTNERNAME="p:CN=mycn.com, OU=A, O=B, L=C, C=GB" 
                SNC_MYNAME="p:CN=myname.com, C=GB, O=A, OU=B" 
                SNC_QOP="8" SNC_MODE="8" TRACE="2"/>          
        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
</SAP.Middleware.Connector>
```

Comment: How did you find this out? Specifically, the CN,OU, etc. info in the SNC_PARTNERNAME and SNC_MYNAME fields? What's the difference between SNC_PARTNERNAME and SNC_MYNAME? Is there any info about these fields and what they expect?

Comment: You need the  SAP NCO 3.0 Programming Guide, which should come as a PDF with the connector. If you have a valid SAP Marketplace account you should be able to log in and download it from the marketplace